# Image previews and web workers

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, filereader, web-worker

Is it possible to use the filereader api within a web worker to load images i.e. for previews/thumbails, therefore preventing the main ui thread from blocking.

Something like [this](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image/blob/master/load-image.js) but wrapping the cpu intensive parts (mainly reading the files contents and scaling the image) inside a web worker

Comment: See here for what is available to workers: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html#apis-available-to-workers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a worker it's not possible to access the page's DOM level so you can't create an Image object or a canvas (for the scaling part) so the answer is no since you want to manipulate the image.

It is possible though to load the image files on a web worker via ajax or the `FileReaderSync`, convert it to a base64 data url string and send it back to the main script, but there is no way to manipulate the image in order to create your thumbnails. (unless you know the file spec for png/jpg/bmp formats and want to hardcode a scaling function working directly on the binary string, doesn't look so good huh?)

Answer (score 2):

The main thread is called UI thread because everything related to the UI directly has to happen there. You can't manipulate DOM in Web Worker but you can manipulate binary of the image file within the Web Worker. After image manipulation, you have to transfer the data to the main thread and let it attach it to the DOM. The browser then will render this image within main thread.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, if you can.

- Make an ajax request from the worker to the server, set responseType to arraybuffer and responseText to response.
- On the server lets say PHP load the requested image into a GD representation (createImageFromJpeg).
- Get each pixel information(imagecolorat).
- Extract the RGBA colors, (pack) each of them and add them to a string.
- Send that string back to the worker.
- Make an new Uint8Array from the response.
- Do some manipulation.
- Commit the ownership to the main script.
- Add the data to a canvas.

Something to read:[Sending Arraybuffer](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/), [Transferable Objects](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/12/Transferable-Objects-Lightning-Fast)

To write down the whole script would go beyond the scope.